# How to set layer mask only on terrain trees?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna use Physic.Raycast with layerMask option. In editor, i can only set layer mask of whole terrain, not only trees. Setting layer mask on trees prefabs doesn't work too. What should i do?
Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RayThings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cam2;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask mask;
    public Camera cam;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDistanceRay;
    private void Update(){
        Ray();
        DrawRay(); 
    }
    private void Ray() {
        ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
    }
    private void DrawRay() {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistanceRay, mask)) {
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * maxDistanceRay, Color.blue);
            cam2.transform.position = hit.point;
        }
        if (hit.transform == null) cam2.transform.position = new Vector3(999f, 999f, 999f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't setting layer mask on tree prefabs work? Can you also share your code

Comment: i dont know why setting layer mask on prefabs dont work, and this is why i asked this

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to set the tree prefab a layer mask? Do you set it at and then the code doesn't register the trees or you don't have the option of setting it at all

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand you. When i spawn non-terrain tree prefab, it works.

Comment: What I am saying is, "doesn't work" is ambiguous and doesn't give off much information. What I'm interested in is:

Have you tried assigning the tree a layer mask and checking with code whether the ray hits it? If you have tried, what happens? Does the ray recognize that there is a tree there, or does the ray hit the terrain behind it? Or maybe something else entirely happens which is why I invite you to share more details than just "doesn't work" Screenshots help a lot too. Share what exactly you're trying to achieve too.

Comment: Ray recognize the tree, but he thinks tree has not correct layer mask.